# Вывод массива в DetailView yii2

Tags: yii2

Как правильно вывести массив в DetailView?
Попробовал так:

```
[
            'attribute' => 'participants',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                $id_participants = explode(",", $model->participants);
                if (!empty($id_participants)) {
                    foreach ($id_participants as $id_user) {  
                        $username = User::find()->select(['username'])->where(['id' => $id_user])->all();
                        foreach ($username as $value) {
                            $participants = '<span class="fa fa-user"></span> '.$value->username;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return $participants;
            }
        ],
```

выводит только одного пользователя
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: $participants .=

Comment: Спасибо, работает :)